# Node Js TypeError with morgan: app.use is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, typeerror, morgan

I am new to node js and following a tutorial on [scotch.io](https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-node-express-and-postgres-using-sequelize). I've imported morgan for logging requests, but when I run the code I get **TypeError: app.use is not a function**. This is my code for app.js;

```
const express = require('express');
const logger = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express;

app.use(logger('dev'));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.get('*', (req, res) => res.status(200).send({
    message: 'Welcome to deep thinking.'
}));

module.exports = app;
```

And for package.json:

```
{
  "name": "postgres-express-react-node-tutorial",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start:dev": "nodemon ./bin/www",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.18.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`require('express')` returns a function, which you should call in order to get the express application. Therefore:

```
const app = express;
```

should be changed to:

```
const app = express();
```

Comment: Wow thanks! This worked. I've been struggling with this for a while.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, change `app=express; to app=express();`

```
const express = require('express');
const logger = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express(); // changed this line

app.use(logger('dev'));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.get('*', (req, res) => res.status(200).send({
    message: 'Welcome to deep thinking.'
}));

module.exports = app;
```